# Bad dark image quality on react-native app

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an application that will have a dark background image.

[image]

Using code:

```
const SignInScreen = () => {
return (
    <ImageBackground source={require("../../assets/images/Desktop1.png")} style = {styles.bgImage}></ImageBackground>)}
```

in styles.bgImage i have only flex:1

in the emulator I see a picture in poor quality and with a lot of black spots:

[image]

what am I missing? in this simple thing